# How to get the file name and the second line of all CSV files in directory into another CSV file?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I need to analyze the results provided in a list of CSV files where I need to have the file name and its second line, this for the set of files of the result directory  in a single output. I found on Stack Overflow a piece of code to get the file name and a piece of code to get the second line of a file. Frankly it is beyond my knowledge to patch them together.

This is what I have so far:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo "filename secondline"    
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s *.*') do (@echo %%~nxa 
    set filename=%%~a
    echo %filename%
    pause
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %i% in ('findstr /n /r . %filename%') do(if %i% geq 2 if %i% leq 2 echo %j% )
    rem pause
)
endlocal
```

How to get the file name and the second line of all CSV files in directory into another CSV file?

Comment: the variable-Syntax of your second `for` is wrong (`%i%` instead of `%%i`) Also insert a space between `do` and `(`. Beside that: good "Patchwork", but Mofi's Code is more efficient - especially with big csv files.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you want. So let me add some information about what I understood.

There are some CSV files in a directory like `C:\Temp` which is the current directory on executing the batch file which contains for example:

**C:\Temp\DataFile1.csv**

```
first name,second name,address,country
John,Doe,"20 Baker Street, Nowhere",Fantasy Island
x,y,anywhere,anyland
```

**C:\Temp\DataFile2.csv**

```
first name,second name,address,country
Jane,Doe,"5 Hammer Lane, Somewhere",Happy Island
x,y,anywhere,anyland
```

And in same directory one more CSV file with name `ExtractionResults.csv` should be created containing finally for this example:

```
"C:\Temp\DataFile1.csv",John,Doe,"20 Baker Street, Nowhere",Fantasy Island
"C:\Temp\DataFile2.csv",Jane,Doe,"2 Hammer Lane, Somewhere",Happy Island
```

The file names in first column should be quoted in case of one of the CSV files have a comma in file name.

For such a task the following commented batch file could be used:

```
@echo off

rem Name of results file without file extension with or without path.
set "ResultsFileName=ExtractionResults"

rem Delete a perhaps already existing results file from a previous run.
del "%ResultsFileName%.csv" 2>nul

rem Delete also a perhaps already existing temporary results file from
rem a not completed previous run. A temporary file with a file extension
rem different to CSV is used for the results in case of results file is
rem created also in current directory with file extension CSV. This must
rem be done to avoid that the second line of the results file is included
rem in the results, too.
del "%ResultsFileName%.tmp" 2>nul

rem Call for each CSV file in current directory the subroutine
rem GetSecondLine with full name of the CSV file.
for %%I in (*.csv) do call :GetSecondLine "%%~fI"

rem Use command MOVE instead of RENAME to rename the file in case of results
rem file name is specified at top with an absolute or relative path as the
rem command RENAME does not allow as second parameter a file name with path.
move /Y "%ResultsFileName%.tmp" "%ResultsFileName%.csv"

rem Exit this batch file and return to parent batch file or command processor.
goto :EOF

rem This is a subroutine. It prints to the temporary results file
rem just the second line or nothing if the file contains just 1 line.
rem The execution of goto :EOF results here in exiting the subroutine.
:GetSecondLine
for /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%L in ("%~1") do (
    echo "%~1",%%L>>"%ResultsFileName%.tmp"
    goto :EOF
)
goto :EOF
```

Well, the code above contains more comment lines than commands. But for an even better understanding of the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `del /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `move /?`
- `rem /?`

And read also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>>` and `2>nul`.